# sharing images from drawable

Tags: java, android, share, drawable

i'm trying to send images from my app, but it only sends one image (the one mentioned in the code below `image_intro`.
i want the app to share whatever image the user chooses.

Here is the code i used:

```
// Share event start
final Button share = (Button) findViewById(R.id.share);
share.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.image_intro);
        String path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)+"/LatestShare.jpg";
        OutputStream out = null;
        File file=new File(path);
        try {
            out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        path=file.getPath();
        Uri bmpUri = Uri.parse("file://"+path);
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
        shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bmpUri);
        shareIntent.setType("image/jpg");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent,"Share with"));
    }
});
```

im counting in your help friends, thanks

Comment: Please edit your post so all code is in the grey code block.

Comment: If you want to send a different image you have to change `R.drawable.image_intro`. What else?

Comment: greenapps thanks for your response, i managed to solve by adding this two lines: ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.backgroundPreview);
   Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)image.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

Comment: Please write an answer yourself and accept it, so the question is displayed as resolved and as a reference for future users with a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

i managed to solve it by adding these two lines:

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ba‌​ckgroundPreview); 
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)ima‌​ge.getDrawable()).get‌​Bitmap();
```